# Time complexity of iterative Fibonacci algorithm with arbitrary length integers

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Consider the straightforward iterative algorithm for computing the *n*th Fibonacci numbers (where *n* is an integer of arbitrary length), as described in the following pseudocode:

```
create an array F[0...n]
F[0] := 0
F[1] := 1
for i from 2 to n:
  F[i] := F[i-1] + F[i-2]    // <--- why O(n)?
return F[n]
```

Can someone explain why, according to my algorithms course, this algorithm has time complexity `O(n^2)`?

In particular, why does the marked step above have time complexity `O(n)` (according to my algorithms course) as opposed to `O(1)` even though it's just an addition of two integers?

Or was I given wrong information?

Comment: The image you put is the core of this question. Apparently this image is flawed. The use of `n` is quite ambiguous. So, you can talk to the coursera tutor for more understanding. I think even editing the question to add more clarity won't help. Hence, unsalvagable.

Comment: I don't think the use of `n` is ambiguous at all here. `n` denotes the input parameter to the Fibonacci function. And the question asks why adding the two integers has time complexity O(n), which is not obvious but correct. I don't think the question is unsalvageable.

Comment: @Henry It doesn't say that is *n* is bounded.

Comment: @MoB. If n is not bounded, we can no longer assume that the result fits in one word. F(n) is O(phi^n) and log F(n) is then O(n) and we get indeed an O(n) effort for this line.

Comment: @Henry Exactly.

Comment: Put it simply what others already said: F(n) is O(n) bits long, and addition processes those bits in constant-length chunks, e.g. bytes, hence the time cost of a single addition is O(n).

Comment: I would like to see this question reopened. The OP's original version was unclear, but after heavy editing it's become an acceptable question, and certainly not "opinion-based".